# Generate token Symfony flex with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle 2.4

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I just tested symfony flex with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle2.4, I followed  [**here**](https://github.com/chalasr/lexik-jwt-authentication-sandbox/tree/flex)

Error is **NotFoundHttpException
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". The route is wrongly configured.**

do I have to create a controller? not sure!
or what is it like stupidity

this my security file:

```html
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: 
            algorithm: bcrypt
  
    providers:
        entity_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
       
        users:
            id: App\Metier\Provider\UserProvider
        
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                provider: users
                check_path:    /login_check
                success_handler:                  lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure


        register:
            pattern:  ^/register
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            provider: entity_provider
            anonymous: false
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/personnel, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

My route.yml and My private key:

```html
api_login_check:
        path: /login_check

 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,1F2589373C3622EADA0262E3D18FBA51
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: route.yml is that a typo? shouldn't it be routes.yml?

Comment: Thanks. yes,route.yml is that a typo,  it is routes.yaml.

Comment: Can you launch `bin/console debug:router` to see which routes in understand by your application ?

Comment: the routes are well understood by my application

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, because I used **json_login in firewalls**,so we had to do as to authenticate with postman:

```js
{
 "username":"bla",
 "password":"blabla"
}
```